# Prevent search engines from indexing individual files in a member area

Tags: wordpress, authentication, bots

We've built a basic members area in WordPress that shows a list of PDF files to users when they are logged in, depending on their role. Incidentally the files can be accessed directly if you know the path to them, say https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/the-file.pdf for example.

But we are now wondering if this is enough to prevent search engines from indexing the PDF files.

We know that if a search engine bot attempts to index the members page, it will not be able to because the bot is not authenticated.

But, if a logged in member accesses the PDF in the browser - again say https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/the-file.pdf - can this file be indexed by a search engine and potentially be seen in search results? We are operating under the belief that the browser (Chrome) could potentially let Google know of the existence of these PDF files and then index them.

If so, what additional precautions should be taken to prevent potentially sensitive PDF files from being indexed by a search engine when logged in, and yet still allow them to be viewed in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with sensitive data you'd also want to prevent **users** from guessing the url (either manually or via script)

Adding authentication when accessing the file should solve your problem and also prevent unauthorized users from getting it.

You can either only allow access to logged-in users or use a short-lived server-generated token that the user sends to the server when trying to access the file.

There are other methods as well.